# How to simplify my code?

Tags: jquery, forms

**UPDATE :**
Here's my horrible jQuery code : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/hdep9/39/)

**NOTE :**
Only the "contact" button contains a true form.

I would like to simplify my code.

I have two forms but one can be show one at the same time : form_devis and form_request.

How to write : If form_request is VISIBLE, that each its fields with class .required and aren't empty, so do this {}. Thank you in advance.

```
    .error-image {background: #c3c6c7 url(../images/erreur-form.png) no-repeat 98% center;}

$btnValidate.click(function() {
    valid = true;

    if ($('#form_request').is(':visible')) {

        $('#form_request').find('.required').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == " ") {
                $(this).addClass("error-image");
                $ErrMessGen.fadeIn(500);
                valid = false;
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass("error-image");
            }

            $(this).keyup(function() {
                if(!$(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).removeClass("error-image");
                }           
            });

            $(this).focusout(function() {
                if($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).addClass("error-image");
                }           
            });
        });

    }

    return valid;

});
```

Comment: `if(!$(this).val() == '')` is wrong because `!` has higher precedence than `==`. It should be `if (this.value) { ... }`

Comment: You should not bind event handlers in `.each()` functions.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** the original example on jsfiddle is now fixed and working: http://jsfiddle.net/akhikhl/EYV2k/

Here is the solution:

```
function validateFormInput(elem) {
  var validElem = !$(elem).hasClass('required') || $(elem).val().trim() != ''
  $(elem).toggleClass("error-image", !validElem);
  if(!validElem)
    $ErrMessGen.fadeIn(500);
  return validElem;
}

function validateForm() {
    var formValid = true;
    $('div.panel:visible input').each(function() {             
        if(!validateFormInput(this))
            formValid = false;
    });
    if(formValid)
        $ErrMessGen.hide();
    return formValid;
}

$("div.panel input").on("keyup focusout", validateForm);

$btnValCt.on(Modernizr.touch ? 'tap' : 'click', validateForm);
```

Explanation:

- validateFormInput checks an individual input element for validity.
- validateForm checks all text input elements on the form
- check for "required" class is moved to validateFormInput, because it is tightly coupled with the rule being checked (there might be other rules and other classes, all they should be made implementation detail of validateFormInput).
- toggleClass simplifies code, so there's no need to call addClass and removeClass separately.
- the two divs "form-demande" and "form-devis" are supplied with class="panel" to simplify code.

Comment: you forgot about `valid` variable

Comment: Thanks for careful reading. I introduced the variable formValid, also updated the example at jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation ! I updated my question with a JSFiddle link. In fact I use modernizr + hammer for touch device and I have a problem with $('#btnValidate').click(validateForm); now.

Comment: Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/akhikhl/EYV2k/ - all things working now. I updated explanation above.

Comment: Wow, great, thank you so much. As against, the buttons no longer behave correctly. When I click again on a form button the form who corresponds to it doesn't disappear and stay grey :-/

Comment: Ah, so that was your intension to do it that way? I thought it's a bug :))

Comment: Ok it's really cool from your part to help me.

Concerning the buttons, I wanted to create a behavior like that : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/AzDQm/4/)

In this example when the button is red I wanted to show up the corresponding form (quotation or request).

I updated your code with the textarea required : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/hdep9/46/)

For the futur errors messages you advised me to do directly with the HTML (span hide) or jQuery ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I correctly understand the last question. What should mean "do directly with HTML"?

Comment: Sorry lol, I'll add errors messages with regEx. Do you advise me to add the error messages directly in the html code (with hidden span) or dynamically with jQuery "append('<span>......</span>');" ?

Comment: I saw in your code that you used "div.panel", it means that I have no longer need to use id="form-demande" or id="form-devis" ?

Comment: Regarding messages: if they are static, it's fine to implement them as spans and just do show/hide/toggle. If text of error messages to be generated dynamically, then you'd better off setting them from javascript.

Comment: Regarding "div.panel": no, you still need ids "form-demande", "form-devis" to address divs in $btnFormCt.on callback. The idea behind "panel" class is the following: you have two panels that behave identical (difference is only in contained fields). You address this "uniformity" by assigning the same css-class to both and then referring divs in code via this css-class.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to improve your code would be to use jquery validate plugin, it will handle empty string checks etc for you and has inbuilt email checks etc.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add the following in your code to prevent form submission by default :

```
$('#btnValidate').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
.......
});
```

Every thing else seems working in your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N6MNY/1/)

Also you could replace `$(this).val()==''` by simply `!$(this).val()` and also you could use
`$.trim` to remove white space from beginning and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

I commented all the edits of your code. I think this is all you can get from it.

As `Ohgodwhy` said event handlers shouldn't be used in `each` because you create X event handlers to single selectors instead of one event handler to all the selectors at once (memory usage).

**updated** my code and got it working.

```
$btnValidate.click(function() {
  valid = true;
  var $formRequest = $('#form_request'); // local variable to find ID only once 
  var $req = $formRequest.find('.required');
  if ( $formRequest.is(':visible') ) {
    $req
    .each(function() {
        if( ! $.trim( $(this).val().length ) ) {  // trim value to get only one IF and use length instead of value&type comparison
            $(this).addClass("error-image");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("error-image");
        }
    })
    .bind({ // alternative method of writing events from about jQuery 1.7. 
        keyup: function(){
            ( $(this).val().length ) && $(this).removeClass("error-image"); // Javascript hack for IFs without ELSEs
        },
        blur: function(){
            ( ! $(this).val().length ) && $(this).addClass("error-image");
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! I updated my question. I tried your code but I can't make it work. I'm bad with jQuery. Probably because I forget "return valid;"  in my code. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

heres by quick and dirty attempt

i seperated the binings completey from the each loop, because i think it makes more sense

```
$btnValidate.click(function() {
    valid = true;
    $('#form_request:visible').find('.required').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).val().trim()) {
            $(this).addClass("error-image");
            valid = false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("error-image");
        }
    });
});
$('.required').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val().trim()) {
        $(this).removeClass("error-image");
        }           
    }).focusout(function() {
    if(!$(this).val().trim()) {
    $(this).addClass("error-image");
    }           
});
```

and an update

Comment: Thank you ! I updated my question because, with your code the form is always validated.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant

```
$btnValidate.click(function() {
    valid = true;
    $('#form_request:visible .required').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        valid = $this.val().trim();
        $this.togleClass("error-image", !valid);
    }
}

$('#form_request').on("keyup focusout",".required",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("error-image", !$this.val().trim());
});
```